# How do I allow ipad access to local IIS ports?

Tags: ipad, iis

We have a few test iPads in the office that we want to test our site out on to iron out a few bugs.
The preferred method is to allow the iPads access to our local IIS ports, so we can make changes on the fly and have them show up on the iPad.

Our network guys are a little scared of just whacking a wireless dongle on our desktop machines, and setting up a wireless hotspot that we can browse to.
So is there another option?
Perhaps only allowing the wireless connection access to certain ports on the local IIS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is more a serverfault.com type of question or even superuser.com

Comment: 2 years later, did you find a good answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you just get the MAC Addresses of the ipads and set up a rule so that those MAC addresses can access it.